# How to save values in different tables from single view using MVC4

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, stored-procedures

Hey I am new in MVC and I am trying to creat a demo application in mvc4 with below description

1. Create a view with five fields

   (a) Student Name

   (b)Student Father Name

   (c)Student Mother Name

   (d) Student Class

   (e)Student Section

Where Student Name, Student Father name, Student Mother name save into Student_Personal_Information table and Student Class and Student Section is save into Student_School_Information table.

1. Create Two tables in SQL Server with below field

   (a) In Student_Personal_Information table

   ```
   (I) Student_Id int (identity)(Primary Key)

   (II) Student_Name varchar(200)
   ```

   (III) Student_Father_Name varchar(200)

   (IV) Student_Mother_Name varchar(200)

   (b) In Student_School_Information table

   (I) Student_Class_Id (identity)(Primary Key)

   (II) Student_Id int (FK with Student_Personal_Information table's Student_Id column)

   (III) Student_Class varchar(20)

   (IV) Student_Section varchar(5)

Note :- Those data save in table with the help of stored procedure

Now my problem is that how can I save all fields data in two Separate(Student_Personal_Information and Student_School_Information) tables using MVC4.

### Now I am Edit My Question

I am also creating a partial view and give the Student Class and Student Section field into partial(strongly type) view now how can I achieve my task

Any Help will be Appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
      1.Create a view with five fields
```

(a) Student Name

(b)Student Father Name

(c)Student Mother Name

(d) Student Class

(e)Student Section

```
       **strong text**
   Now when  submit your View i.e form   and access the model values in your controller . 

    and pass the model values separately to your Tables Like below . 

        Student_Personal_Information.Name = model.Name  
        Student_Personal_Information.FatherName = model.FatherName                Student_Personal_Information.MotherName = model.MotherName             

 and rest of details in another table 

    Student_School_Information.Class=model.class
```

Student_School_Information.Section=model.Section

```
  Hope This helps you.
```

Comment: your suggestion I also used.